# Get product Collection with all product with category id

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I'm trying to get product collection and join table catalog/category_product.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
                        ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left');
```

And I have the error.
Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "338" already exist.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: one product can be from multiple category

Comment: I understand that. And how can I filter my product collection by product id?

Comment: what exatly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to take all products in all stores and adding to them category ids.
I try to use ->addCategoryIds(), but it doesn't work. May be Iim doing some mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please use this collection.**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: I tried this method. I had the error:
Notice: Undefined index: l  in /var/www/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145

Comment: And I think it's the same like my version.

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. My error is not related to this. I fixed problem, but I still use ResourceModel.

Answer (score 0):

My category id is

```
<?php $catid=10 ;?>
I got all product by writing the below code

    <?php
    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($catid); //My cat id is 10
    $prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($prodCollection as $product) {
    $prdIds[] = $product->getId(); ///Store all th eproduct id in $prdIds array
    }?>

Now you have all the product ids in `$prdIds` variable. 

Just click here to get all details of the product from a particular product id.

You can get individual product id by the following loop.

    <?php
    foreach($prdIds as $_prdIds){
    $product_id = $_prdIds;
    $obj = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’);
    $_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
    // get Product’s name
    echo $_product->getName();
    //get product’s short description
    echo $_product->getShortDescription();
    //get Product’s Long Description
    echo $_product->getDescription();
    //get Product’s Regular Price
    echo $_product->getPrice();
    //get Product’s Special price
    echo $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    //get Product’s Url
    echo $_product->getProductUrl();
    //get Product’s image Url
    echo $_product->getImageUrl();
    }
    ?>
```